# VBA is giving error 13 "Type Mismatch" datatypes range

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I am trying to write a code to take a specific name from a column and match a date with it in a next one,

```
Sub ContractDates()

    Dim StatusValue As Range
    Dim QuotationOpen As Range
    Dim DateWriter As Range
    Dim x As Long
    Dim rFind As Range

    lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastrow
        Set StatusValue = Cells(x, 4)
        For Each c In StatusValue
            If StatusValue = "DESIGN" Then
                Set QuotationOpen = Cells(x, 3)
                For Each v In QuotationOpen
                    If QuotationOpen = "Q3ING18" Then
                        Set DateWriter = Cells(x, 7)
                        Let DateWriter = "28/09/2018"
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

And It is giving me the error on the line that says

```
If QuotationOpen = "Q3ING18" Then
```

But not on the line that says

```
If StatusValue= "DESIGN" Then
```

Even though they are both 'range'
And I can't figure out why

Comment: What is the idea of `Let DateWriter = "28/09/2018"`? Is it better to write `DataWriter.Value = = "28/09/2018"`.

Comment: What is the need for `For Each c in StatusValue` or `For Each v In QuotationOpen` since `StatusValue` and `QuotationOpen` are both just single cells?

Comment: @Vityata I wanted it to match the row where QuotationOpen is Q3ING18. But I will try

Comment: @bigben I didnt think of it I immagined them being the range of cells in that column. Basically what I wanted to do is for every q3ing18 in the column C, The date 28/09/2018 gets written in the column G

Comment: But they're not the range of cells in that column - you set them to be a single cell with `Cells(x, 4)` and `Cells(x, 3)`. You're iterating down the column with `x`... Do you have to do this with VBA? Seems like you could use a formula. `=IF(AND(C4="Q3ING18",D4="DESIGN"),DATEVALUE("28/09/2018"),"")`

Comment: I have other Dates to match with weird names from the same column

Comment: If you're just matching names to dates, can you use a `Vlookup` against a table of the matches?

Comment: It's giving me a circular reference error

Comment: `=IF(D14="DESIGN";VLOOKUP(C14;Sheet3!A:B;G:G;FALSE);"N/A")` I'm trying this formula but its giving me an error as a result

Comment: Those `;` should be `,`. Also check your syntax in `Vlookup`: the 3rd argument is the column index number (e.g. 2), not a column.

Comment: I tried switching the `;`to `,`it gave me an incorrect syntax, so i left them and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: I would familiarize yourself with [Vlookups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1). The use of the semicolon is foreign to me but maybe [this setting](https://lockone.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/excel-now-using-semicolons-instead-of-commas-in-separating-formulas-fix-it-now) is applicable in your case. If so, you still need to fix the 3rd argument in the Vlookup.

Comment: I did but it did not change anything , `=IF(D14="DESIGN";VLOOKUP(C14;Sheet3!A:B;7;FALSE);"N/A")`

Comment: Again, please read about Vlookup. Your specified range to look at - `Sheet3!A:B` - only has 2 columns and you're telling Excel to look at the 7th column.